# How to find a amplifier that named "ISP" on a circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, components, high-pass-filter

I am analyze the [circuit](https://backyardbrains.com/products/files/Neuron.Spikerbox.Pro.V1.pdf). I can't find any relation about the name ISP of a op-amp. When we look the high pass filter we see there "ISP" name. I search it on google but I can't find nothing related.

I also check other circuits of backyardbrains, than I see there are two "ISP" named components. [Example](https://backyardbrains.com/products/files/Schematics-Muscle-spikerShield-Pro-V1.pdf) at virtual ground part.

What is that?

[image]

Comment: Make it easy for your readers. Which op-amp are you asking about? Give the component designator(s).

Comment: @Transistor I added a image. The op-amp is named as ISP. I can't understand.

Comment: We neither. You have to find documentation about the circuit which describes the info. It looks like custom made Eagle component and even the default pin names are not changed.

Comment: I can't find. I just notice that the component is also used in other projects. [example](https://backyardbrains.com/products/files/Schematics-Muscle-spikerShield-Pro-V1.pdf)  look the part named "Virtual Ground". I see each component's code, so I thought that the "ISP" is a special name.

Comment: Instead you may use TLC227x series OPAMP as it is used in the other sections of the design.

Comment: A better way is to name the designators with A and B markings, like TP11A and TP11B that way they can be identified *which part they belong to*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect that ISP means "In Same Package" or "In Same Part": -

[image]